# Sql getting different AVG from the same select and table

Tags: sql

I am working on the northwind database for my sql studies and i`m trying to show How many Employees live in each country and their average age.
This is what i managed to do so far:

```
select Country,COUNT(EmployeeID) 'AmountOfEmployees',
(select AVG(year (getdate()) - year (birthdate)) from Employees where Employees.Country = 'USA') 'USA_Average_Age',
(select AVG(year (getdate()) - year (birthdate)) from Employees where Employees.Country = 'UK') 'UK_Average_Age'
from Employees
group by Country
```

and the result is:

[image: QueryResult]

I cant seem to manage to get different avgs on the same column for UK and USA. is it even possible?
Hope i was clear with my question.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you use a Scalar Subquery (`(select avg ...`) instead of simple `avg`?

Comment: You are right,i`m unsure why i thought a subquery is the way to solve this. i tired "select Country,COUNT(EmployeeID) 'AmountOfEmployees',avg (year (getdate()) - year (birthdate)) 'Avarage_Age'
from Employees
group by Country" and it seemed to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subqueries are not necessary.  I may not approve of your calculation for age, but you can use it:

```
select Country, COUNT(EmployeeID) as NumberOfEmployees,
       avg(year(getdate() - year(birthdate)) as average
from Employees
group by Country;
```

This puts the average on different rows.